# What stowed items can a Tiefling's prehensile tail retrieve?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, pathfinder-society, tiefling

The prehensile tail ability is written thus:

> Prehensile Tail: Many tieflings have tails, but some have long, flexible tails that can be used to carry items. While they cannot wield weapons with their tails, they can use them to retrieve small, stowed objects carried on their persons as a swift action. This racial trait replaces fiendish sorcery.

The question is what constitutes small items?  In my opinion, the immediate things I think about are wands, potions, spell components, metamagic rods, keys, foodstuffs, but is there a definitive list as to the cutoff of stowed items?

For example: I use my prehensile tail to retrieve a dagger stowed in my belt. While I do not use the tail to wield said weapon, I transfer the weapon from the tail to my hand to wield.  Is there also weight or shape considerations for this maneuver? (Retrieving a wand is different than say retrieving a ball, or a box, or a plate, etcetera)

Comment: Tagging this [pathfinder-society] means you're looking for official rulings on this trait for use in organized play. Is that accurate?

Comment: Both would be appreciated but yes it is for a PFS character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple answer would be 'GM's discretion'.

There has been discussion on the Paizo forums about [possible things you could grab](http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2pm8s?Prehensile-Tail-small-objects#8), effectively having 'Quick Draw' for none weapons. Some are suggesting light weapons could be pulled with it, but I believe this traits is more designed for very small light objects less than one pound (which would be potions, scrolls, many magic items, coinage, etc) as explained in more detail in the [Grasping Tail](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/racial-feats/grasping-tail-tiefling) feat.

Comment: This is what I thought but am glad to have other opinions on the matter